# Mirroring all traffic from one port to another for monitoring in Linux

Tags: port

We recently found a bug in a hardware vendor's ability to port aggregate to a monitoring port. They have given us an estimate og at least 6 months of development to get a fix. As this is an operational requirement for us, we need to figure out another way to get access to this packet data. Is there any way to mirror all traffic from a network interface in linux to another interface (both in and outbound)? Then we could attach the monitoring box to the second port and capture the data there.

Comment: What about just using a tap?  It's the least invasive operationally and it will pretty much always be useful.

Comment: We would love to, however putting it into a production environment would require a lengthy QA period, and we don't really have time for it :(

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Two possible ideas:

- Create a bridge between two interfaces and use `brctl setageingtime 0` to ensure no addresses are learned and all packets not destined to the bridge host are forwarded across the interfaces.
- Sourcefire's [Daemonlogger](https://www.snort.org/downloads#Daemonlogger) can write all traffic on one interface to another interface.

Comment: daemonlogger looks like exactly what we need! I'll give it a shot, thank you!

Comment: Can you give a short explanation of what `brctl setageingtime 0` does?